# I can t find why my bearer token is not valid, its returns 401

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, bearer-token

I have created role-based authentication. Token is generated succesfully.
In my vue app, after login i m adding token to localStorage and then, im sending it in header by use of axios in format:
Authorization: "Bearer"

I m getting unauthorize everytime i m trying to do GET on items.
In postman is this same.

I m using IIS to host my app localy, and as frontend i m using Vue.js

I have already tried:
- authorization and Authorization in header
- changing http to https and vice versa.

Startup ConfigureServices:

```
 #region JWT
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecretKey"));
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
            #endregion
```

Startup Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

My method to generate token based on roles:

```
public User Authenticate(string login, string password)
        {
            var user = Context.Users.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Login == login && p.Password == password);

            if (user == null)
                return null;

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role)
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            user.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);


            user.Password = null;

            return user;
        }
```

And this is my Endpoint (in case if something is wrong here)

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
    {
        public ItemsController()
        {
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Item>> Get()
        {
            var items = new ItemsService();
            return items
                .GetItems();
        }
```

Comment: Look at your server logs, it should tell you why it is rejecting the token. In doubt, set the logging level down to Debug, that should definitely give you the information.

Comment: Its telling nothing. Just some logs about browser that i used.

Comment: You are not looking at the ASP.NET Core logs then.